# .net Can not download image. Request gets blocked, why? (httpwebrequest)

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, download, httpwebrequest

On some domains I can not download images. The code is working with other domains, but with some its doesn't. I can't figure out why. I can download the image with a full browser like firefox or chrome but not with httpwebrequest.
I tried to emulate a full browser as close as possible but no success.

Maybe you can help me to find the error?

Error is:

> A System.Net.WebException exception error has occurred in System.dll.
>   Additional Information: The underlying connection has been closed:
>   Unexpected error while sending

On line:

```
    Dim httpWebResponse = DirectCast(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Here is the code with sample of failling download:

```
    Dim httpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.oglf.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/BestLEDTeethWhitening.jpg"), HttpWebRequest)
    httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-us,en;q=0.5")
    httpWebRequest.Referer = "https://www.oglf.org"
    httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = True

    Dim httpWebResponse = DirectCast(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    If (httpWebResponse.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK AndAlso httpWebResponse.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.Moved AndAlso httpWebResponse.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.Redirect) OrElse Not httpWebResponse.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        Return
    End If
    Using stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Using fileStream = File.OpenWrite("c:\imagetest.jpg")
            Dim bytes = New Byte(4095) {}
            Dim read = 0
            Do
                If stream Is Nothing Then
                    Continue Do
                End If
                read = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, read)
            Loop While read <> 0
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the problem is that the ssl connection negotiation is failing. If is it of no consequence to you that you don't use ssl to connect, I would just use the following:

```
Private Sub DownloadImage(ByVal source As String, destination As String)
    If source.StartsWith("https://") Then source = source.Replace("https://", "http://")
    Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
        wc.DownloadFile(source, destination)
    End Using
End Sub
```

If you must use ssl, try setting the TLS version to 1.2 since some websites require that, and the .net web client doesn't default to that:

```
Private Sub DownloadImage(ByVal source As String, destination As String)
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
        wc.DownloadFile(source, destination)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Called using:

```
DownloadImage("https://www.oglf.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/BestLEDTeethWhitening.jpg", _
              "c:/tmp/test.jpg")
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for answer, but unfortunately this does not work! Same Error!

Comment: I got the same error on my machine when I ran the original code you posted, but both these subs resolved that error and ran without exceptions and saved the image correctly on my machine...so it's strange they're not working for you. I guess you will have to start looking outside your code for what's causing that error, because those requests to that url are fine programatically. So maybe something external like firewalls or webfilters? I dunno, good luck.

Comment: Hi, I just created a complete new vb.net project on different machines (win7/win10) and I get the same error as in the initial post. Are you sure, you used the https version for testing?

Comment: Try the second sub I just edited, setting the TLS version to 1.2 might do it for you so add that, and remove the ServerCertificateValidationCallback handler. Also, does the first one work for you, or do you get errors on both secure/unsecure connections?

Comment: GREAT !!! Your new version fixed the problem !! Thank you very much. How did you narrow down the problem?